# Is it possible to build a tensor with the following properties?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I am searching for a tensor in 4-dimensional space-time with two indices that satisfy:

\begin{eqnarray}
M_{;\mu }^{\mu \nu } &=&0 \\
M^{\mu \nu } &=&-M^{\mu \nu }  \nonumber \\
M_{;\varepsilon }^{\mu \nu }+M_{;\nu }^{\varepsilon \mu }+M_{;\mu }^{\nu
\varepsilon } &=&0  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

An obvious choice would be the electromagnetic field strength, but I am investigating if it is possible to build a tensor with such properties that only depends on geometrical properties of the space-time manifold. For instance, the riemman tensor satisfies two of these properties for fixed $\alpha$, $\beta$:
\begin{eqnarray}
R_{;\varepsilon }^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }+R_{;\nu }^{\alpha \beta
\varepsilon \mu }+R_{;\mu }^{\alpha \beta \nu \varepsilon } &=&0\text{ } \\
R^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu } &=&-R^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

But I found its divergence is zero only in very special cases, such as for maximally symmetric spaces. Is there anyway to build a tensor with these properties always, or at least in not so special cases (such as maximmally symmetric spaces)?

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1023044/11127

Comment: I close this question, since it is crossposted.